# Error after making function wait until event ends

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have the following HTML and jQuery Ajax code:

```
<form>
    <input name="name_field" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".error").hide("blind", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name_field'];

?>
```

When I submit the form, it shows the following error:

```
Undefined index: name_field
```

However, when I change my jQuery Ajax to not wait for the `.error` class to finish, it shows no error and works perfectly fine:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".error").hide("blind"); // remove function() here
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the `this` reference used for serialization, inside the `hide` callback it refers to the `error` element not the form element

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $(".error").hide("blind", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            //this here is not the form element it is the error element
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks a bunch.